# When to use "1" vs. "one" for technical writing?

Tags: numbers, technical

I currently am in the middle of a discussion about the proper use for when to use the numeral "1" versus "one".

There are two sides to this argument:

1) In technical writing, numerals should always be used.

`The company hired 4 interns, but the fifth 1 left`

`Patch management is 1 of the best ways...`

`The client should create a 1-way trust`

2) When using it as a pronoun or as an unspecified measure, "one" should be used.

`One of the things to consider`

`The assessment met one common standard`

Can someone please provide some insight for clarity? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you always use numerals (a ***very*** dubious decision), shouldn't it be *"the 5th 1 left"*? Anyway, that *1* is the pronoun, so it should be *"the 5th one"*. Never use a numeral for the pronoun.

Comment: "The fifth 1 left" is never correct, unless you were referring to a list of five ones (11111) and one "1" "left". As @PeterShor points out, in this case "one" is the pronoun, and would never be numeric. Beyond that, as a general rule, spell out numbers 1-9, but for technical writing, it may be appropriate to always use the numeric version when you're referring to a numeral (as opposed to the pronoun example above).

Comment: In the company style guide that I am referring to, the rule says "Use numerals rather than spelling out numbers, but use first, second, third ..."

Comment: So *"the fifth one left"*. That *"one"* is not a number but a pronoun.

Comment: @salierii - Are you encouraging management to revise the manual?

Comment: @Mark Yes, but I want to make sure that I am thinking about this correctly before I present my case :)

Comment: @salierii - Cool. ... You might want to recommend a specific style guide so that you have: _i)_ an authoratative source to buttress your argument; _ii)_ a recommendation that will save the company money, since you won't need to 'reinvent the wheel' editing the company's style manual; and _iii)_ a single manual that will promote consistency. The APA Style Guide covers many more scientific and technical issues than some folks would expect from a psychological association.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write:

> The company hired 4 interns, but the fifth intern left.

That is in keeping with your style guide and the meaning is much clearer. The "1" in your example refers to a person (the intern) not a number.

If you're looking for other style guides as sources you could try Chicago or, if it's for  technical writing, Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

The cutoff for writing out a number is ten. So one to ten get written out as words, while 11 and beyond are written as numerals.

Comment: The cutoff depends on the publication. And there is something to be said for consistency: *"We discarded 7 of the 26 samples because of radioactive contamination."*

Comment: There is a cutoff, but I would disagree it's ten, because numbers up to twenty are one word, and up to a hundred a maximum of two.

Comment: This was the rule I learned, but the consistency point is very good. Also the logic that numbers up to twenty are essentially the same length is also a good one. There appears to be several valid exceptions to the rule, and now I wonder if its a rule at all or just a style preference.

Comment: It might just be a style preference taught as a rule. I remember learning the cutoff at ten as the default in Chicago.